# C# - ObservableCollection WPF GridView Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, observablecollection

I got a problem to bind an ObservableCollection to a WPF GridView. The ObservableCollection is filled with a custom Objekt (Users).
Then I get the ObservableCollection and try to bind ist to the DataGrid based on this Tutorial:
[ObservableCollection in WPF](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/e06010/observablecollection-in-wpf/)

Here is my Users Class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WpfVPNM.UserObjects
{
    public class Users
    {
        /*Enthält die einzelnen Benutzer mit detailierteren Informationen*/
        private String sam {get;set;}
        private String fname {get;set;}
        private String lname {get;set;}
        private String active {get;set;}

        #region constructor
        public Users(String sam, String active) {
            this.sam = sam;
            this.active = active;
        }
        public Users(String sam, String active, String fname, String lname)
        {
            this.sam = sam;
            this.active = active;
            this.fname = fname;
            this.lname = lname;
        }
        #endregion
        #region Getter/Setter
        public String getsam() { return this.sam; }
        public String getfname() { return this.fname; }
        public String getlname() { return this.lname; }
        public String getactive() { return this.active; }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Here is my Class for holding my `ObservableCollection`:

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WpfVPNM.UserObjects
{
     public class UsersInGroup
     {
         /* Objekt welches die einzelnen Benutzer in den Gruppen enthält */

         public ObservableCollection<Users> UserList = new ObservableCollection<Users>();

         /*Fügt der Liste einen neuen Benutzer hinzu*/
        public void Add(String sam, String active) {
        this.UserList.Add(new Users(sam, active));
    }
    public ObservableCollection<Users> getList()
        {
            return this.UserList;
        }
    }
}
```

And here we have the XAML Definitions, based on the Tutorial named above:

```html
        <ListView x:Name="lstNames" Margin="1,68,0,1" Grid.RowSpan="2">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView x:Name="grdNames">
                    <GridViewColumn Header="sam"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding sam}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="active"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding active}"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

And then finally in the background i want to bind the ObservableCollection to the GridView:

```
        public void renewTableView() {
             /*Beschaffe die Gruppenmitglieder der Gruppe grp_vpn*/
             ADFunctions adf = new ADFunctions();
             UserObjects.UsersInGroup groupMembers =      adf.getGroupMember(DCEntry);

        ObservableCollection<UserObjects.Users> list = groupMembers.getList();
        foreach (UserObjects.Users us in list)
        { 
            Debug.WriteLine("List - " + us.getsam() + ";" + us.getactive()) ;
        }

        lstNames.ItemsSource = list;
        //dgaccounts.ItemsSource = groupMembers.getList();
        Debug.WriteLine("Table AHOI");

    }
```

With the foreach loop I check if the `ObserableCollection` is filled with data, and yes it is. Then I want to set the Source for the Grid View but it doesn´t display any data. Can someone please help me or give me a good working Tutorial?

That would be great :)

Comment: Just a suggestion: you seem to come from Java and the naming convention you are using in your code is not right.
Please, take a look [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/261001/Csharp-Tips-Tricks).

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend you use the MVVM pattern as opposed to relying on the code behind.

So you would create a `ViewModel` which implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` and set this to be the `DataContext` of your View.

To give a simple example, your `ViewModel` would look something like:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<User> Users { get; set; }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        Users = new ObservableCollection<User>()
            {
                new User { Sam = "1", Active = "True", FName ="Test First Name 1", LName ="Test Last Name 1"}, 
                new User { Sam = "2", Active = "True", FName ="Test First Name 2", LName ="Test Last Name 2"}, 
            };
    }
}
```

Then set this to be the `DataContext` in the constructor of your View class (this is just the simplest way to do this):

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this.DataContext = new ViewModel();
}
```

And finally bind your `DataGrid` to the `ObservableCollection`:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Users}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="true">
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Sam}" Width="100"/>
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Active}" Width="100" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Your properties sam, active etc are private.

Usually you declare them this if you want read only properties:

```
private string _sam;

public string Sam
{
 get
  {
    return _sam;
  }
}
```

I highly recommend you to look at the MVVM pattern where you do not reference UI elements from code